# Adding data to DataSource from UI with BindingSource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ado.net, bindingsource

I have a form (Form1) which contains a grid, bound to a DataSource via a BindingSource.

I then have a button, which once clicked opens another form (Form2) that should let a user enter new data.

I pass the BindingSource from Form1 to Form2, and the goal is that once the user "saves" his input in Form2, it'll be automatically added to Form1.

Is there a way to do this, w/o directly accessing the UI controls?

I.E -

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    public Form2(BindingSource bindingSourceFromForm1)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.bs = bindingSourceFromForm1;
            }    
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                DataRow dr = (this.bs.DataSource as DataTable).NewRow();
                dr["Col1"] = this.textBox1.Text;
                dr["Col2"] = this.textBox2.Text;
                this.bs.Add(dr);
            }
}
```

Is there a way to bind the controls on Form2 (in the example above textBox1/2) to the BindingSource, and then have it automatically add the values in textBox1 & 2?

Something like calling `this.bs.Add()`, where `Add()` knows where to take it's values without me explicitly telling it to go to the textboxes, since it's bound to the aforementioned controls?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `BindingSource` to the form designer as you would normally do, set the `DataSource` to the same source so you can bind the textboxes.

In the specialized constructor the following code adds a new record to the `DataSource` of form1, assigns the DataSource to the DataSource of the `BindingeSource` instance of this form and sets the position. Your new Form will enable the user the enter the values in that new object.

```
public Form2(BindingSource bindingSourceFromForm1)
    : this()
{
    bindingSourceFromForm1.AddNew();
    this.bindingSource1.DataSource = bindingSourceFromForm1.DataSource;
    this.bindingSource1.Position = bindingSourceFromForm1.Position;
}
```

If your user can cancel the operation you have to compensate for that by calling [`RemoveCurrent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.removecurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) on the `bindingSourceFromForm1` but I leave that as excersice as it is not clear if you want/need that.

Comment: But where does AddNew() take the values from? How does it implicitly know that Column 1 is mapped to Text box 1 (as I explicitly did in my example)? Does it do it by being bound to the relevant fields via the BindingSource? Because calling AddNew() seems to create an empty row, even though I have the text boxes bound to the DataSource fields

Comment: I see, So, what's the difference between the code you wrote and the one I wrote? You create a new row in the constructor, I created it when the user clicks the button. Am I missing any other difference?

Comment: Yes, that the binding is design-time on the form, can be used to use the designer to set/change the mapping of controls, automatic type conversion on bind, synchronized values on multiple forms/controls, have the possibility a BindingNavigator per form. So I see a couple of advantages. But if I missed the essential part of the issue you want to get an answer for you might need to clarify the question a bit.

Comment: But the things you mentioned also occur with the code I posted in the original post... no? 
I'd still like to understand the difference between yours and mine, I guess I'm misunderstanding you...

And the main part of my question was whether I have a way to access the bound controls via the BindingSource, w/o accessing them directly (textBox1.Text), which you said I can't.

Comment: The difference is that in your code you create a new instance of a BindingSource. That one doesn't have any bindings to any controls because that is setup in the form.designer.cs code. The bindimgsource doesn't know which controls it is bounded  (at least not public available). The control does know where it is bound to by inspecting its `DataBindings` collection where you can also `Add` a binding if needed.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!